# How can I log work time for a JIRA issue in Tempo using REST?

Tags: python, rest, jira, time-tracking

I am working on a small multi-platform Python application.

It should display JIRA issues which the user is assigned to.
The user should be able to log work against those issues.

The server we're using has Tempo and that seems to be the way that management wants to log time.

Is there a way to use REST with Tempo to log work?
Or should I just use the Tempo API to log work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Tempo just utilizes the standard work log you should be able to use the REST api to log work and that should show up in tempo.

The API for logging time in JIRA using REST can be found here:

http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#id123143

Comment: Thanks! Also, would you know if that would support the "Work Type" field? In our instance of Jira we are required to use the Work Type drop down before we log time with Tempo. Edit: Or just a Custom field.

Comment: I can't find any reference to that in the API no, but you could make that change in the database if you have a trigger that checks the work log table (which ever it is) and look for unclassified work logs and change the work type from there every time an entry is made.

Answer (score -1):

Below Tempo rest API is use for posting “work log” for specific issue (ISSUE-911) for logged in user for Given range date

https://0.0.0.0/jira/rest/tempo-rest/1.0/worklogs/issue-911